# How can I wire multiple recessed lights and multiple dimmers?

Tags: electrical, wiring, recessed-lighting

How do I wire recessed Zinc Alloy ceiling lights.  There are eight lights and eight dimmers.

Can I run all wires and the feed into a junction box?

Comment: We need a bit more information - what voltage? what kind of connectors are on the lights? what type of dimmers are they? etc.

Comment: Also it is important that you include where you live.

Comment: You really want each light to have its own dimmer?  Why not two zones or something.  That is just weird.  Any reason that each has to be on its own dimmer?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a one-switch-per-light configuration, you'll need to run a cable from the switch electrical box to each light.  So you'd have the line coming into the box, and then the hot would go to each switch, and then from each switch to each light.    All of the neutrals would be tied together.

This of assumes that a single circuit can handle the load of all of these lights - have you done any load calculations yet?  You also have to watch out for the box size as code states the maximum number of wires in each box depending on the size.

There might be other ways to accomplish this (extra wires for travelers, etc.) but we'd need more information on your setup to help provide any insight here./

Comment: for a 15V circuit each light would have to be over 150 watts to make an impact.

Comment: @DMoore, I believe you mean a 15A circuit. And that assumes there isn't anything else connected to that circuit. If it's an existing circuit that's being expanded, it may already be near capacity.